# Proving a shift operation is a group action, and proving the orbits have size $p$ or 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

Let $K$ be a nonempty set, and let $p$ be a prime. Let $X=K^m=\{(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m):a_i\in K\}$. Let $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ act on $X$ by  the shift operation: $j\cdot(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_j,a_{j+1},\dots,a_p):=(a_{j+1},\dots,a_p,\dots,a_j)$.

Prove this is a group action. Prove that every orbit of ths action has size 1 or $p$ and that the orbit is size 1 only for the elemnts of the form $(a,a,\dots,a)$.

I can see that to prove that there exists an identity, if we set $j=0$, then each $a_i$ will not shift at all, so $0$ is the identity.

To prove the second requirement of a group action, I can see that $h\cdot [j\cdot(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_j,a_{j+1},\dots,a_p)]=(a_{h+(j+1)},\dots,a_p,\dots,a_{h+j})$. However, I'm having trouble equating that to $(hj)\cdot(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_j,a_{j+1},\dots,a_p)$.

For the second question about orbits, I don't understand how I would go about this proof, so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: For your second requirement of group actions, use associativity of addition: $h+(j+1) = (h+j)+1$. In your context of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, $hj$ means $h+j$.

Comment: For the orbits, see how 1 acts on an element $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m)$, where not all the entries are the same. Then keep composing that action until you get back to the original m-tuple.